# Including playbook in a playbook and defining environment file

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook. When I run the playbook I specify which environment file to use.

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/release-deploy.yaml -i env/LAB3
```

Within the ansible-playbook I am calling another playbook and I want the same environment file to be used.

My current config is:

```
 - include: tasks/replace_configs.yaml
```

So when I run the playbook, I get the error:

```
TASK [include] *****************************************************************  
fatal: [10.169.99.70]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "reason": "no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to have been in '/home/ansible/playbooks/tasks/replace_configs.yaml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- hosts: cac
  ^ here


The error appears to have been in '/home/ansible/playbooks/tasks/replace_configs.yaml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.


The offending line appears to be:

---
- hosts: cac
  ^ here
"}
```

`tasks/replace_configs.yaml` also needs to use `env/LAB3`

Looks like it doesn't know what `cac` is. Do I need to do another config ?

Comment: Share your include file as well as env file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My current config is:
>
> ```
> - include: tasks/replace_configs.yaml
> ```

This is not any "config", this is a line which includes a file containing **tasks**.

Let's look at the following "task":

> ```
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> ---
> - hosts: cac
>   ^ here
> ```

It does not look like a **task**, it looks like a **play**. It most likely does not contain any module directive, so Ansible rightfully complains that there is no module name provided in the task it expected: `no action detected in task`.

When you use `include` directive in Ansible it puts the included content at the indentation level of the `include`, so when you include tasks, you should include **only** tasks

Your included file should look like:

```
---
- name: This is a task
  debug: msg="One task"

- name: This is another task
  debug: msg="Another task"
```

and should not contain any other definitions, particularly those belonging to a higher level.

Comment: Thank You for the detailed answer. It worked perfectly as soon as I removed the - hosts line.